# Canon EOS 5D Mark II Lens

Tags: canon, canon-5d-mark-ii

I am using a Canon EOS 600D with a `EF-S 15-85mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM` lens - by far the best lens I ever owned. Since I am in the process of switching to a 5D Mark II, which lens would be the equivalent for a FF camera?

I am having some interest in the `Canon EF-S 15-85mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM`. Is it worth trying it out or are there any alternatives you would recommend? My budget is around $450 USD (second hand).

Comment: Biggest issue: ef-s lenses won't work on the 5d. Ef-s lenses are designed for crop sensors...the image circle isn't big enough for full frame and you could even damage parts because the full frame mirror can slap the rear of an ef-s lens. Look for ef lenses instead.

Comment: Based on what you've written, it looks like you already own the same lens you are interested in. The EF 24-105/4L will give you a FOV similar to the EF-S 18-85/3.5-5.6. Where to go from there depends on your personal preferences.

Comment: Why would you be interested in buying another copy of the same lens you already own (which won't work on a FF camera such as the 5D Mark II)? I'm guessing you meant another lens, but you need to let us know which one it is.

Comment: Looks like a copy-and-paste error. Please review your question.

Answer (score 1):

Focal-length-wise, a 15–85 EF-S lens is like a 24–136 on a full-frame camera, if such a beast existed.  So if your goal is to match that field of view, the closest equivalents are the 24–105L (or L II) and the 28–135.

My experience with the 28–135 was that the build quality isn't up to par, and many copies tend to not stay at a given zoom setting when tilted up or down.  I ended up shipping the one I bought back to Amazon and sticking with the 24–105L.  I do still miss that bit of extra reach (coming from a 17–85, in my case), but not enough to deal with such a floppy lens.  Obviously, your mileage may vary.

Tamron and Canon also both have 28–300 lenses.  The former, of course, produces lower quality because of its size, weight, and zoom range, whereas the latter is an absolute beast of a lens (at nearly 4 pounds), and is still an image quality compromise.  But they do exist as options, if you're trying to do nearly everything with a single lens.  I have no experience with either one personally, so if you decide to go that route, let us know what you think about it.